# UIBarButtonItem not showing up ios 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm having an issue where the UIBarButtonItem is not showing up. I'm adding it via the storyboard, and when I do

```
println(self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem)
```

it is not nil and gives me a proper reference to the button

Yet, the item seems like its hidden.

I am using a navigation controller and a tab bar controller in my application also, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason is that the bar button is off the screen (you can check this by looking at the width of the tool bar or nav bar in which you have placed the bar button). A quick way to confirm that is the issue is to select the view controller screen in the storyboard; then, on the Menu bar, select Editor -> Resolve Auto layout Issues -> All Views -> Reset to suggested constraints. This should result in a layout that Xcode considers reasonable. If the bar button is off screen, this will suck it back in. Alternately, in the same menu, you can "Clear Constraints" followed by "Add Missing Constraints".

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the issue Apple describes in the release notes for Xcode6.2 beta (not sure if this is what you are using). The fix would be to go to declaration of the class for the controller, and instead of "class" type in "@IBDesignable class".